# count all select list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to count all the select list where its value selected as 1. All the selected list has a class called 'sllist'. And how to do If I want to update the count in to hidden field when a select list selected value change to 1. plz help.

```
<select id="status_1971" class="sllist" size="1" name="status_1971">
<option value="0">Disable</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Enable</option>
</select>

<select id="status_1975" class="sllist" size="1" name="status_1975" disabled="disabled">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Disable</option>
<option value="1">Enable</option>
</select>

<select id="status_1974" class="sllist" size="1" name="status_1974">
<option value="0">Disable</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Enable</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".sllist").change(function() {
   var len = $(".sllist").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() === "1";
    }).length;
    $("input").val(len);
}).change();
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/MNzDw/1/)

Answer (score 3):

a very simple way...

```
$('select.sllist').change(function(){
   $('#my_hidden_field').val($('option:selected[value="1"]').length);
}).change();
```

fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/MNzDw/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = $('.sllist option:selected[value=1]').length;
```